# Python SQLite update error

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm writing some scoring server using python and sqlite, and error occured when using update.

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from server import *
>>> db = DB_control()
>>> db.update_user_score("ZSPEF1", "FXVCWI", 180)
UPDATE score SET FXVCWI = 180 WHERE USER_ID = ZSPEF1
Error raised while updating ID ZSPEF1's score to 180. Rolling back DB...
DB Successfully rolled back
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "server.py", line 102, in update_user_score
    musica_db.execute(update_score_str)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ZSPEF1
>>>
```

score table looks like this:
[image: score table screenshot]

As you see, there are FXVCWI column and ZSPEF1 row and want to change that value, but error says there are no ZSPEF1 column.
UPDATE command only occurs error on update_user_score function.

Why this happens to me?
Also, error sometimes occurs when first character in string is number. Is there any way to prevent this error?

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

musica_db_file  = sqlite3.connect("musica.db")
musica_db  = musica_db_file.cursor()

class DB_control(object):
    def setupDB(self):
        #This function should execute only on first run.
        try:
            userDB_setupDB_str   = "NUM         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            userDB_setupDB_str  += "CARD_ID     TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            userDB_setupDB_str  += "NAME        TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            userDB_setupDB_str  += "PASSWORD    TEXT NOT NULL, "
            userDB_setupDB_str  += "ADMIN       INT  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"

            songDB_setupDB_str   = "NUM         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            songDB_setupDB_str  += "SONG_ID     INT  NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            songDB_setupDB_str  += "NAME        TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            songDB_setupDB_str  += "FINGERPRINT TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE"

            scoreDB_setupDB_str  = "USER_ID     TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE"

            musica_db.execute('CREATE TABLE user({0}) '.format(userDB_setupDB_str))
            musica_db.execute('CREATE TABLE song({0}) '.format(songDB_setupDB_str))
            musica_db.execute('CREATE TABLE score({0})'.format(scoreDB_setupDB_str))
            musica_db_file.commit()

            self.add_user(randomID(), 'MU_Admin', 'yj809042', admin=True) #Create admin account.
            self.add_song(randomID(), 'Tutorial', randomID()) #Create tutorial(dummy) song
            print("DB setuped.")
        except:
            print("Error raised while setuping DB")
            raise
    def update_user_score(self, cardID, songID, score):
        try:
            update_score_str = "UPDATE score SET {0} = {1} WHERE USER_ID = {2}".format(songID, score, cardID)
            print update_score_str
            musica_db.execute(update_score_str)
            musica_db_file.commit()
            print("User ID {0}'s score is now {1}.".format(cardID, score))
        except:
            print("Error raised while updating ID {0}'s score to {1}. Rolling back DB...".format(cardID, score))
            self.rollback_DB()
            raise
    def rollback_DB(self):
        try:
            musica_db_file.rollback()
            musica_db_file.commit()
            print("DB Successfully rolled back")
        except:
            print("Error raised while rolling back DB. Critical.")
            raise
```

Comment: I think you need quotation marks around user_id

Comment: @fodma1 That didn't work for me.  "UPDATE score SET {0} = {1} WHERE 'USER_ID' = {2}".format(songID, score, cardID)

Comment: @LeeM.U. not like that. I meant the actual id`"UPDATE score SET {0} = {1} WHERE USER_ID = '{2}'"`

Comment: Side note: you  apparently add a new column for each new song. That's not like the relational Dbs are supposed to be used. You probably may want to read  about `many to many relationship`

Comment: @robyschek Oh, i should search about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fodma1 This worked too, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interpolating column values as *SQL object names*, with no quoting:

```
update_score_str = "UPDATE score SET {0} = {1} WHERE USER_ID = {2}".format(songID, score, cardID)
musica_db.execute(update_score_str)
```

Don't use string interpolation for SQL *values*. Use bind parameters instead:

```
update_score_str = "UPDATE score SET {0} = ? WHERE USER_ID = ?".format(songID)
musica_db.execute(update_score_str, (score, cardID))
```

The `cursor.execute()` function will then take care of proper quoting, reducing your risk of SQL injection.

Even interpolating SQL object names (`songID` here) is dodgy; do make sure you validate that string up front.

It looks as if you are creating a column per song. You probably want to read up some more about proper relational table design and *not* store data in column names. Use a `user_song_scores` many-to-many table instead, where that table stores `(USER_ID, SONG_ID, SCORE)` tuples, letting you update scores for a given song with `UPDATE user_song_scores SET score=? WHERE USER_ID=? AND SONG_ID=?` instead, removing the need to generate column names.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I'm new to DB so i didn't know about many-to-many table. Maybe i should re-write my code ;)